# How to set log level for apache beam pipeline running on Direct Runner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When running an Apache Beam pipeline locally using [Direct Runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) the log level seems to be set to `DEBUG`.

Is there a way to set the log to say `INFO` instead?

Note: `--workerLogLevelOverrides` can be used when using Cloud Dataflow Runner, but does not seem to apply on Direct Runner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that per standard configuration, the logging is done with `slf4j` using a `JUL`(`java.util.logging`) backend. You can check in your pom.xml for `slf4j-api` which corresponds to `slf4j` and `slf4j-jdk14` for its backend.

You need to configure JUL at runtime. One way is to pass as a parameter to the VM something like

`-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties`

Then you create a `logging.properties` in the directory where you run your application. In my case it is the root directory for the app(the one that contains `src` directory). If it doesn't seem to work, you can just specify an absolute path in as the filename.

Regarding the configuration, here you have an example:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.level=ALL
```

This sets the level for the package `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource`. Depending on the situation you can play with it's configuration. Make sure that the level is properly set to all the components involved in JUL log output.